# tikz circle with text and auto enlarge

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to draw circle with some para inside of circle which need to be enlarge based on text within the circle. I am new in tikz package, could you please help. Please find my MWE file:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows,positioning,fit,calc,}
\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
                \draw [fill=blue,draw=red, ultra thick] (0,0) circle (3.0cm)
            node  {Sample text Sample text
Sample text
Sample text };
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is a para?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to dial a `circle` node.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,fill=blue,draw=red, ultra
thick,align=center,text=white,font=\sffamily\bfseries]  {Sample\\ text Sample\\ 
text Sample text\\
 Sample text Sample\\ text Sample\\ text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\usepackage[right]{eurosym}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,fill=blue!80,blur shadow,align=center,text=white,font=\sffamily\bfseries]  
  {Since the launch\\ 
  of the Eastern Partnership\\
  initiative in 2009,\\
  the EIB has committed\\
  \textcolor{yellow!80!orange}{\large \euro\,8.8\,Billion}\textcolor{white}{, supporting}\\
  \textcolor{yellow!80!orange}{\large 96 projects}\\
  \textcolor{white}{in the region.}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you your valuable solution, this is we required exact output.